# How to output the first N letters of the names of each subdirectory of a given directory?

Tags: command-line, bash

Need to  output the first N letters of the names of each subdirectory of a given directory.
I thought to use ls command, but don't know where and how to write names of the files

Comment: Where do you want the names to be written to - to a file or the console?  You can use **ls -1** to get a list of names.

Comment: yes, to the console, but how to write only 5 letters of each name, without whitespaces? in one line

Comment: You could use sed.  See https://linuxhint.com/50_sed_command_examples/#s37.  Just change the 80 to 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-printf` action of the `find` command accepts a C-style `%.N` field width specification

```
find path/to/directory/ -type d -printf '%.5f\n'
```

(replace `5` by your desired number of letters *N*). Add `-maxdepth 1` to limit it to immediate subdirectories.

---

If you want all files, it's even easier. You can either use `find` as above but drop the `-type d`, or use `stat` with a simple `*` shell glob:

```
find . -printf "%.5f\n"

stat -c '%.5n' *
```

If you want to use a shell variable for the width, then you will need to change the quotes i.e.

```
N=5
find . -printf "%.${N}f\n"
```

or

```
N=5
stat -c "%.${N}n" *
```

If you have "simple" filenames and just want something quick'n'dirty to use in the terminal, you could even use

```
ls | cut -c1-$N
```

Comment: and how to insert my variable N in this?
thanks^_^

Comment: @MariaMilovanova see edits - please remember to include **all** your requirements in your questions

Comment: thank you very much!!!!